# Build a customized Google Datalab container locally

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm following the documentation in the getting started guide: https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/wiki/Getting-Started

As instructed, I updated "containers/datalab/Dockerfile.in" to:

```
# Use this file to create a new docker image derived from the standard datalab image

FROM gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:latest
#MAINTAINER name name <email@example.com>

# The following line will install package fbprophet, as an example
RUN pip install fbprophet
```

After I updated the dockerfile.in I tried to run:

> ./build.sh && ./run.sh

But, my local instance of datalab still did not have the package installed.

I've never used docker before so I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: What error did you get? Do you have Docker installed? What OS are you using?

Comment: No error. Datalab still runs locally but the custom package I installed is not available. I'm either running the wrong container or did not run the build command correctly.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps for "Using your modified Datalab image on GCE"? Consider that since you just created a new Datalab, if your datalab instance was created before following those steps, this won't have the new datalab image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to source the virtualenv. Assuming you want to use `python3` as your kernel try adding the following to your docker file:

```
RUN source activate $PYTHON_3_ENV && \
    pip install fbprophet && \
    source deactivate
```